# Bash commands not working after SFTP script

Tags: linux, centos, bash, sftp

I have the following bash script

the SFTP works fine but the echo "Backup done" dosnt work

```
#!/bin/sh
sftp -b /dev/stdin server <<EOF
  cd /shares/backup/webserver/
  put $bu_PATH$BACKUP_FILE
  quit
  EOF

echo "Backup done"
```

Can any one help?

Comment: even with a semicolon after last EOF?

Comment: @mailq - yup even with that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EOF is not at the beginning of the line.  Changing your script to:

```
#!/bin/sh
sftp -b /dev/stdin server <<EOF
  cd /shares/backup/webserver/
  put $bu_PATH$BACKUP_FILE
  quit
EOF

echo "Backup done"
```

should make it work.

You might replace `/dev/stdin server` by `-` as the latter means stdin.

Answer (score 0):

That should be a lower-case "echo" instead of "Echo".

Comment: well said - thats a typo in the question

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to improve the process a bit by just echoing the long string to the command.   You would eliminate the hanging file created to hold those few lines:

```
 #! /bin/sh
 echo "cd /shares/backup/webserver/
 put $bu_PATH$BACKUP_FILE
 quit" | sftp -b - server

 if test $? -ne 0
 then
      echo Backup Problem
      exit 1
 fi

 echo 'Backup DONE!'

 exit 0
```

Notice that the echo line continues over the CR's until another matching quote is discovered.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#! /bin/sh
printf "%s\n%s\n" "put $bu_PATH$BACKUP_FILE" "quit"  | sftp -- user@server:/shares/backup/webserver/
if (( $? )); then
   echo "Backup Error."
   exit 1
fi

echo 'Backup DONE!'

exit 0

if test $? -ne 0
then
      echo Backup Problem
      exit 1
fi

echo 'Backup DONE!'

exit 0
```